# Programmatically create EHCACHE self populating caches on startup

Tags: java, reflection, ehcache

When the application starts I want to create `EhCache Manager` and automatically assigning available `CacheEntryFactories` to cache regions for self-population.

So the operative sequence is:

1. Locate `ehcache.xml` configuration
2. Create CacheManager instance
3. Detect `CacheEntryFactories` that could be assigned
4. Create and replace `selfPopulatingCaches` using those factories

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue putting all factories in a package, naming them with a given pattern and using `reflection` to create instances, creating `SelfPopulatingCaches` and replacing them using `replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache()`. Here's the code snippet:

```
File configurationFile = new File(EHCACHE_CONFIG_PATH);
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(configurationFile);   
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.create(configuration);

for(String cacheName : manager.getCacheNames()){

    Cache cache = manager.getCache(cacheName);

    try {

        Ehcache selfPopulatingCache = createSelfPopulatingCache(cache);

        if(selfPopulatingCache != null){
            manager.replaceCacheWithDecoratedCache(cache, selfPopulatingCache);
            log.info("Factory for cache '" + cache.getName() + "' created.");
        }           

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error creating self-populating-cache for '" + cache.getName() + "'", e);
    }

}


private Ehcache createSelfPopulatingCache(Ehcache cache) throws Exception{

    CacheEntryFactory factory = null;

    String factoryClassName = "com.myproject.factories." + Utils.capitalize(cache.getName()) + "CacheFactory";

    Class factoryClass;
    try {

        factoryClass = Class.forName(factoryClassName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Unable to find factory for cache " + cache.getName());
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * factory may need some extra resource (dataSource, parameters)
     * organize factories in abstract classes with their constructors
     * and ask for factoryClass.getSuperclass() i.e:
     *
     *  if(factoryClass.getSuperclass().equals(AbstractDatabaseCacheFactory.class)){
     *      Constructor constructor = factoryClass.getConstructor(DataSource.class);
     *      factory = (CacheEntryFactory)constructor.newInstance(DataSourceListener.getDataSourceMaster());
     *  }
     *
     */
    Constructor constructor = factoryClass.getConstructor();
    factory = (CacheEntryFactory)constructor.newInstance();

    return new SelfPopulatingCache(cache, factory);

}
```

in package `com.myproject.factories` I will put classes like

```
AccountsCacheFactory.java
EmployersCacheFactory.java
BlogPostsCachFactory.java
```

That will be the factories for `accounts`, `employers` and `blogPosts` cache regions.